# Very low test score result in sklearn diabetes dataset on plotting the learning curve with decision tree

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I have a question regarding the diabetes dataset on sklearn. I am trying to plot the learning curve for a type of estimator, but somehow I have the warning:

> "D:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.p
>   ing: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too
>   nimum number of labels for any class cannot be less than n_folds=3."

and the code is plotting a weird result. The training dataset has a very high score (always 1, which maybe makes sense since it is a tree), but the test score performs very poorly (0.03125 at its best)

I tried it in different dataset (digits) and it worked fine. The code that I have is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve
from sklearn import tree


diabetes = load_diabetes()
X, y = diabetes.data, diabetes.target


estimator = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
estimator.fit(X, y)

title = "Learning Curves Decision Tree"
plt.figure(1)
plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel("Training examples")
plt.ylabel("Score")
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X, y)

print train_sizes
print train_scores
print test_scores

plt.grid()
plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores, 'o-', color="r",label="Training score")
plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores, 'o-', color="g",label="Cross-validation score")

plt.legend(loc="best")

plt.show()
```

Can anyone please give me an explanation why this happens? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `diabetes` dataset represents a [regression problem rather than a classification problem](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning-predicting-an-output-variable-from-high-dimensional-observations), and is therefore unsuitable for testing `DecisionTreeClassifier` on. According to [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html#linear-model-from-regression-to-sparsity):

> The diabetes dataset consists of 10 physiological variables (age, sex, weight, blood pressure) measure on 442 patients, and an indication of disease progression after one year

The `target` vector should be treated as a continuous (or at least ordinal) dependent variable that you need to predict the value of, rather than a set of categories.

If you treat `target` as a set of class labels then you end up with a total of 214 classes, most of which have only a single member (hence the warning message). In this situation your fitted decision tree essentially behaves like a "look-up table" that can perfectly map each `X` value in your training set to its corresponding `y` value, but has zero predictive value for the unseen examples in your cross-validation set. This is a particularly extreme example of [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).